# Tailwind Config

Tags: css, frameworks, tailwind-css

please don't roast me.

I tried to enable dark mode in tailwind. The documentation said that I need to set it in my config.

so here is what I do

```
npm install tailwindcss@latest postcss@latest autoprefixer@latest
```

then I make the config file

```
npx tailwindcss init
```

And put this code in it

```
module.exports = {
  purge: [],
  presets: [],
  darkMode: "media", // or 'media' or 'class'
  ....
  ....
}
```

the dark mode is still not enabled, what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  darkMode: 'class',
}
```

and HTML

```
<!-- Dark mode not enabled -->
<html>
<body>
  <!-- Will be white -->
  <div class="bg-white dark:bg-black">
    <!-- ... -->
  </div>
</body>
</html>

<!-- Dark mode enabled -->
<html class="dark">
<body>
  <!-- Will be black -->
  <div class="bg-white dark:bg-black">
    <!-- ... -->
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

also try to rebuild your project

Comment: hi, thank you for your answer! I've tried them but how to rebuild the project? I am sorry, i already google but still don't get it :(

Comment: If you are using plain HTML then you can't rebuild your application. It's needed when you use React or some other frameworks. Sorry if I've confused you :)
Did dark theme start working?